# Is there a way to store organization-wide settings in a Slack app?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm doing research for a new Slack app that will require the admin adding the app to paste an API token and request url for the third-party API which the app will call. I can't find anywhere in the Slack API docs to store these settings on an app-wide basis. Can this be done via environment variables of some type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slack Apps don't really store settings like that. You would need to persist them in a data store of your choice, like MySQL, Dynamo etc and access them from your code.

Comment: Via an API? I'd still need keys. Or does a Slack App have a data store that's common to all instances of the app for a particular Workspace? Is it like an iframe?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Slack Apps don't provide a data store. You can get a key for a *single* workspace/org from the app config pages, but for multiple workspaces/orgs you'll need to implement an [OAuth flow on your server](https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2), and store the keys in a datastore you provide.

Comment: An admin user of our app would have the ability to onboard the Slack app and do OAuth _one time_. Then the Slack App needs to store these keys to our web service on a workspace level so that other users can interact with it without performing OAuth themselves. Does this make sense?

Comment: So when you say “do oauth one time” you mean to _your_ service right? Not Slack’s own oauth flow? If so, then yes, you’ll need to store those tokens somewhere you provide, not slack.

Comment: If you’re talking about a literal piece of UI for a user to input credentials, you could probably use the App Home tab as the UI, but again the credentials will need to be stored by you.